# Detect when I do brute force attack and block the connection

Tags: webserver, brute-force, ubuntu

My server (Ubuntu + LAMP) is infected, as I receive security alerts from the sites attacked from my IP.

> your Server/Customer with the IP: ********** has attacked one of our servers/partners.
>   The attackers used the method/service: *bruteforcelogin*  on: *Sat, ** *** 2015 17:15:17 +0200*.
>   The time listed is from the server-time of the Blocklist-user who submitted the report.
>   The attack was reported to the Blocklist.de-System on: *Sat, ** **** 2015 21:27:10 +0200*

Is there a tool or method to detect if I do an attack and to block outgoing connections to it ? Or receive at least an alert ?

Comment: I would be more concerned about kicking the intruder out from your system as to try and block the outgoing requests.

Comment: @BadSkillz, Yes, I'm agree. But after a week without search results, I think it's better to block the connections at least.

Comment: @SpartakusMd if you close the connection they might just open it again if they have access to your machine.

Comment: What have you found so far about the infection? Anything from the virus scanner or IDS?

Comment: @S.L.Barth, I removed many obfuscated scripts. Even `FilesMan` was found. Many script files which `exec`uted the code from `$_POST`. Now, `Clam AV` doesn't report anything, git is clear (it was added after the intrusion).

Comment: @SpartakusMd - if you're using a clean git state as a way to ensure that code hasn't changed, I'd advise checking for commits that you don't recognize, and added/modified .gitignore files. Personally, I'm fairly sure I could hide malicious code in a way that a casual git inspection (especially a simple `git status`) won't reveal.

Comment: Please read [Serverfault: How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 3):

One way to mitigate this issue would be to implement egress filtering on your network.  For example most web servers should have no requirement to make connections to the SSH ports of arbitrary hosts on the Internet, so if you block this traffic at the firewall your systems become less useful to attackers

Also this can help reduce the risk of compromise in the first place, as egress filtering can make establishing active control of your systems harder (not impossible, but it raises the bar a bit).

If you want to go down the detection route, a network intrusion detection system (e.g. [snort](https://www.snort.org/)) could be used to alert on unusual traffic patterns like brute-force attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Fail2ban is an interesting tool for that. From the official wiki page [1](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page):

> Fail2ban scans log files (e.g. /var/log/apache/error_log) and bans IPs
>   that show the malicious signs -- too many password failures, seeking
>   for exploits, etc. Generally Fail2Ban is then used to update firewall
>   rules to reject the IP addresses for a specified amount of time,
>   although any arbitrary other action (e.g. sending an email) could also
>   be configured. Out of the box Fail2Ban comes with filters for various
>   services (apache, courier, ssh, etc).

Comment: Fail2Ban is used to mitigate attacks on the server itself, not to prevent outgoing attacks.